# Accessing a geometry type database field from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, geometry

I am under a POSTGRESql database using the PosGis module and i need to access a database field from a Delphi application which is a GEOMETRY type field.
By Using a FieldByName('...').AsString, it creates me an error.

Is there a way to get this data in Text/String format from SQL or in Delphi please ?

Thanks
Gwenael

Comment: We can't guess the error. We aren't all familiar with this particular DB schema. Please tell us more!

Comment: I got a 'field not find'. My query is correct, so i don't know what to do

Comment: I don't know what to do either because your question is too vague and contains practically no information to allow you to gain help. Sorry.

Comment: What database provider are you using (TADOConnection, PGDAC, etc...)? What is the exact error text and the type of the exception?

Comment: If you use `fieldbyname` is handy if the field actually has a name, if it's an expression you need to give it an alias like `SELECT espression(x) AS x2` then you can use `fieldbyname('x2')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use PostgreSQL data type casting - `SELECT ... <expression>::text ...`

Comment: The correct answer is the ST_AsText() fonction.Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no Delphi field type that could match, it is up to the middleware/driver used to access it to transform it into another datatype, or supply an ad-hoc class to implement the specific field behaviour. I guess the Delphi standard one doesn't - look for someone that does, or you may have to access the Postgres client API directly.